# After migrating from 2010 to 2016 Document upload is not asking for properties

Tags: document-library, 2016

We have migrated from 2010 to 2016 recently in Development environment for testing purposes. We had a document library in SharePoint 2010 when users upload document it asks for properties to be filled as shown in fig [image] But after migration the document is uploading directly without any prompt for properties. There is no content type involved in here, this is a simple document library that I am using here.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure you have required fields in 2016 or they won't be prompted to enter properties.

[How to Ensure that Users are Prompted for Document Metadata in Office 365 and SharePoint 2016](https://www.computerworld.com/article/3045118/microsoft-subnet/how-to-ensure-that-users-are-prompted-for-document-metadata-in-office-365-and-sharepoint-2016.html)

Comment: This is interesting though I did not made any field mandatory I have changed the Allow management of content types to be checked and it is working fine now. But in 2010 neither required is not needed nor Allow management of content types is needed, This is kind of breaking the user-friendliness in 2016. That's weird from MS.